# OpenCV counting vehicles

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm done with detecting vehicles in OpenCV C++ but i need to count them, not counting cars in "frame". i need to count all the cars passed. This is my detecting code, what am i suppose to do?

```
arac_cascade.detectMultiScale(
    frame_gray, arac, 1.1, 2, 0 | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(20, 20));

for (int i = 0; i < arac.size(); i++)
{

    Point pt1(arac[i].x + arac[i].width, arac[i].y + arac[i].height);
    Point pt2(arac[i].x, arac[i].y);

    rectangle(frame, pt1, pt2, cvScalar(0, 255, 0, 0), 1, 8, 0);
    Mat aracROI = frame_gray(arac[i]);
}
```

Comment: Is that  all of your code (when I cleaned up formatting slightly, noticed you didn't have the ending })?

Comment: no, its not my all code ofc. it's just detecting code. would u help me ? if u need all code i can send u by e-mail.

Comment: if your detection is good enough (finds each vehicle in each frame) and you have a frame-rate that is high enough you can use a simple tracking-by-detection approach and count tracked objects only once until they leave the screen. the next simple approach is to create some kind of "detection spots". when you detect a vehicle in that spot (line/region on a lane) you count it but you dont count additional detections on that spot until there is a single frame where there was no vehicle detected on that spot. Again you need high frame rate and detection accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

After detecting, **`arac.size()`** is the total number of the detected vehicles in current frame. If you need to count the number of all the frames, you can simply **sum them together** like:

```
int num_total = 0;
for (-every-frame-){
    // detection code...

    num_total += arac.size();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, but when i write for(-every-frame-), says for "-every" undefined.

Comment: @BatuhanGüven This is just description code. You cannot directly copy it to run. What I mean is you should loop your detection on each frame, and sum the number.

Comment: I really couldn't do it, actually i didn't understand about "for(-every-frame-)" part. Could u help me more please?